# Hartshorne, algebraic geometry, proof of lemma 4.2 chapter I, section 4 on rational maps

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the proof of lemma 4.2 in section 4 of chapter 4, in the book by Hartshorne, algebraic geometry, 1977, it is stated that the morphism $\phi$ from $H$ to $\mathbb{A}^n$ corresponds to a homomorphism of rings $A\rightarrow A_f$, where $A=k[x_1,...,x_n]$. Is this a minor inaccuracy in his notation? I started to formulate this homomorphism of rings for myself, and wondered what this homomorphism would be. The hypersurface $H$ is the zero loci of the polynomial $x_{n+1}f(x_1,....,x_n)-1$. Is Hartshorne saying in his proof of lemma 4.2 that this homomorphism maps from $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ to $k[x_1,...,x_n]_f$ or should I understand this homomorphism as a map from $k[x_1,...,x_{n+1}]$ to $k[x_1,...,x_{n}]_f$ where $x_i\mapsto x_i,i=1,...,n$ and $x_{n+1}\mapsto 1/f(x_1,...,x_n)$. The homomorphism in the latter version would be in line with the definition of a ring homomorphism (preserving addition, multiplication and mapping $1_A$ to $1_{A_f}$).

Lemma 4.2 goes as follows [a commentator asked me for more context]:

"Let $Y$ be a hypersurface in $\mathbb{A}^n$ given by the equation $f(x_1,...,x_n)=0$. Then $\mathbb{A^n}-Y$ is isomorphic to the hypersurface $H$ in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ given by $x_{n+1}f=1$. In particular, $\mathbb{A}^n-Y$ is affine, and its affine ring is $k[x_1,...,x_n]_f$."

The proof starts as follows:

"For $P=(a_1,...,a_{n+1})\in H$, let $\phi(P)=(a_1,...,a_n)$. Then clearly $\phi$ is a morphism from $H$ to $\mathbb{A}^n$, corresponding to the homomorphism of rings $A\rightarrow A_f$, where $A=k[x_1,...,x_n]$...."

The proof goes on, but the remainder is not relevant to my question.

My question concerns this last sentence which quoted here

Comment: Could you please provide us with the exact statement of the lemma, for those of us who don't have the book within reach? It would be nice to know, for instance, what exactly $H$ and $\phi$ are, and what we are actually trying to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H$ is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ cut out by the ideal $(x_{n+1} f - 1)$, so its coordinate ring is
$$k[x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}] / (x_{n+1} f - 1).$$

But $k[x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}] / (x_{n+1} f - 1)$ is just $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]_f$.

---

**EDIT:** Reading the question again, I'm not clear on which part you're confused about, so here is some further explanation.

The morphism $\phi : H \to \mathbb{A}^n$ takes a point $(a_1, \ldots, a_{n+1})$ on $H$ to the point $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ on $\mathbb{A}^n$.  That is, it drops the last coordinate (which is redundant information anyway, since we for any point of $H$ we have
$$a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{f(a_1, \ldots, a_n)},$$
i.e. the last coordinate is determined by the others anyway.)

Consequently, the induced ring homomorphism takes a coordinate function $s : \mathbb{A}^n \to k$ to a the coordinate function $(s \circ \phi) : H \to k$.  That makes $\phi^\ast$ a map from $k[\mathbb{A}^n]$ to $k[H]$, i.e. a map from $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ to $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]_f$.

Comment: The coordinate ring $k[x_1,...,x_{n+1}]/I(Y)$ is isomorphic to $k[x_1,...,x_{n}]_f$, as I understand you. I believe I misunderstood something later on in my question. In fact, I realised that there is an isomorphism $k[x_1,...,x_{n+1}]/I(Y)$ with $A_f$ by applying the mappings $x_i\mapsto x_i,1\leq i<n+1$, and $x_{n+1}\mapsto 1/f(x_1,...,x_n)$, but then I messed up some concepts. Are you implicity using the argument that there is a homomorphism from $A=k[x_1,...,x_{n}]$ to $k[x_1,...,x_{n+1}]/I(Y)$? Furthermore, are you denoting by $\phi^*$ the comorphism of $\phi$?

Comment: If you agree with Hartshorne that $\phi$ is clearly a morphism from $H$ to $\mathbb{A}^n$, then you agree that the induced map $\phi^\ast : k[\mathbb{A}^n] \to k[H]$ is a ring homomorphism, because that, by definition, is what it means for $\phi$ to be a morphism.